# Keep JTable Stationary in JScrollPane When Resizing Columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a `JTable` inside a `JScrollPane`.  The user scrolls to the right.  I then enlarge by `x` pixels a column to the left of where the user is looking.  This causes the table to appear to scroll left.  How do I adjust the `JScrollPane`, `JScrollBar` or `JViewport` to keep the table stationary?  In other words, how do I keep the same visible portion of the table on the screen?

I tried adjusting the horizontal `JScrollBar`'s value by `x`.  I also tried adjusting the `JViewport`'s view position by `x`.  The problem is that the table ends up scrolling to the right.

Here is the code that shows the problem without any of my attempts to keep the table stationary.

```
package oracle.psr.ndr.guiclient.util.table;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public final class StableColumnResizing extends JFrame
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 738732002168497075L;

   private final TableColumnModel m_model;
   private final JScrollBar       m_bar;
   private       int              m_colIndex;

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(StableColumnResizing::create);
   }

   private static void create()
   {
      StableColumnResizing frame;
      Timer timer;

      frame = new StableColumnResizing();

      frame.setVisible(true);
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(frame::moveRight);

      timer = new Timer(1000, frame::adjust);

      timer.start();
   }

   private StableColumnResizing()
   {
      JScrollPane pane;
      JTable table;
      Object rowData[][], columnNames[];

      columnNames = new Object[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29};
      rowData     = new Object[][]{{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}};

      table   = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
      m_model = table.getColumnModel();
      pane    = new JScrollPane();
      m_bar   = pane.getHorizontalScrollBar();

      table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

      pane.setViewportView(table);

      add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      setSize(1024, 768);
      setLocationByPlatform(false);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }

   private void moveRight()
   {
      m_bar.setValue(m_bar.getMaximum() / 3);
   }

   private void adjust(@SuppressWarnings("unused") ActionEvent event)
   {
      TableColumn column;
      int count;

      count = m_model.getColumnCount();

      if (m_colIndex >= count)
         return;

      column = m_model.getColumn(m_colIndex);

      column.setPreferredWidth(200);
      m_colIndex++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the request of others, I created some simple code to show the problem.  With that simple code, it became easy to create the solution.

The solution adds a new method `getX()` and adds more code to `adjust()`.  `getX()` computes the left-most position of the column before making any column size changes.  This value is stored in the local variable `x`.

The solution also captures the `JScrollBar.getValue()` before making any column size changes.  This value is stored in the local variable `value`.

After the column size is changed, then compare `x` < `value`.  This is true if the left-most position of the column is off the left side of the view.  If true, then add the difference in column width to `value` and call `JScrollBar.setValue()`.  Thus, columns off the left side of the view will cause the scroll bar to be shifted enough to keep the visible columns in view.  Columns to the right will simply be adjusted.

Becareful of `TableColumn.getMaxWidth()`.  The width of the column will honor this when setting the width of the column.  The code to handle `getMaxWidth()` is below even though it has no impact to the UI since the original post does nothing not call `TableColumn.setMaxWidth()`.

```
private void adjust(@SuppressWarnings("unused") ActionEvent event)
{
   TableColumn column;
   int count, old, next, value, x, max;

   count = m_model.getColumnCount();

   if (m_colIndex >= count)
      return;

   x      = getX(m_colIndex);
   value  = m_bar.getValue();
   column = m_model.getColumn(m_colIndex);
   old    = column.getPreferredWidth();
   max    = column.getMaxWidth();
   next   = 200;

   column.setPreferredWidth(next);
   m_colIndex++;

   if (x < value)
      m_bar.setValue(value + Math.min(next, max) - old);
}

private int getX(int colIndex)
{
   TableColumn column;
   int result;

   result = 0;

   while (--colIndex >= 0)
   {
      column  = m_model.getColumn(colIndex);
      result += column.getPreferredWidth();
   }

   return(result);
}
```